# How can I construct a single string from JSON Array using ngFor in Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have the following data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "AAA",
    "desc": "XXXXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "name": "BBB",
    "desc": "YYYYYYY"
  },
  ...
]
```

I am trying to display on the web as `AAA, BBB, ...` with the following code:

```
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="3">
      <div class="text-grid" *ngFor="let value of data; let f=first">
        <div *ngIf="f">
          {{value.name}}
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!f">
          , {{value.name}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
```

But the output result is overlapped. How can I achieve my expected result?

**Edited**
After checking the CSS, it was a issue from CSS:

```
.text-grid {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    color: royalblue;
}
```

I tried to use either `text-align: left` (which does not work within Angular Material grid) or `width: 100%`(which result in a large gap between the items).

Any suggestion on how to tweak the CSS?

Comment: For what purpose you are using `ngIf` ?

Comment: `ngIf` is for adding the comma before the name if it is not the first item

Comment: I guess you don't need to check that since it will run from the first object itself you need to append `,` after `{{value.name}},`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `mat-grid-list` around `mat-grid-tile` and you need to use `<span>` instead of `<div>` as div is block element. see below

```
<mat-grid-list cols="1">
<mat-grid-tile>
  <div class="text-grid" *ngFor="let value of data; let f = first">
    <span *ngIf="f">
      {{value.name}}
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="!f">
      , {{value.name}}
    </span>
  </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: even after using `<span>`, the value output are still overlapped

Comment: can you reproduce this on stackblitz, it looks like some CSS issue and not code

Comment: You are right! I remove the class `text-grid` from `<div>` and they no longer overlap. I will have a look to my CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to wrap your content within `mat-grid-list` , like below -

```
<mat-grid-list cols="1">
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <div class="text-grid" *ngFor="let value of data; let last=last">
        {{value.name}} <span *ngIf='!last'>,</span>
    </div>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mhgj3w?file=src/app/grid-list-dynamic-example.html)

**Extra Tip**: No need to add two `*ngIf`, you can check for `last` index in the `*ngFor` as above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to format your data before putting it in the template

component.ts

```
formattedDate: string = '';
data: any = [
    {
        "name": "AAA",
        "desc": "XXXXXXXX"
    },
    {
        "name": "BBB",
        "desc": "YYYYYYY"
    }
];

formatDate() {
    this.formattedDate = this.data.map(el => el.name).join(', '); // return 'AAA, BBB'
}
```